# Alternative when the current whois email cant be accessed and needs to verify the contact info for ICANN validation

Tags: domain-registrar, whois, icann

I have a domain reseller account under PDR (publicdomainregistry). One of my client's domain has come under "Pending Verification". The message which I see in my control panel is as below.

An email has been sent to the Registrant for verification. If the email address is not verified by Friday, January 13, 2017, the domain name will be deactivated.

The problem is that the client have no access to the current 'Registrant Contact' email. Also I can't change the registrant contact because there is this 'pending verification'.

Is there any other option by which I can overcome this? without the domain getting deactivated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client, who obviously entered the wrong email address, should contact the registry directly and generally provide all sorts of ID.

If you are the reseller, best thing you can do to look after your customer is contact your wholesaler as well and check what the process is.  I doubt it will be easy.

But I reckon you have left your run a bit late.  Your client had 15 days to do this, there are 5 left :(

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Yeah I think now I've to get all the ID proofs. And the client never saw that email (the usual forgotten email ids).  It showed up in my domain control panel. Will update the process once it's through.